# VBA - Macro Won't Keep Score Of Correct Answers

Tags: excel, vba, testing, button

My project uses 6 Command Buttons as possible select one for correct answer in multichoice exam. A hidden sheet contains the questions - four possible answers to each question - and a column display of the correct answer to match against.

Presently the buttons work as desired EXCEPT the macro is not tracking how many correct answers the user has selected (1 - 10 questions).

I need the project to track how many correct answer were chosen and to display that number on the separate UserForm "SCORE". The final score needs to be entered in the worksheet SCORE as well.

Download example workbook :  [Multi Choice Workbook](https://share.internxt.com/d/sh/file/7dc34cb23d653f720fbb/3d7493ee56eb8d2d273fd0bb3796a0ea6f8eb1b0aa85b6fc8a3f132c123e44df)

This is a portion of the code included in the project :

```
    Option Explicit

Private btnClicked As String 'A, B, C, D
Private questionNo As Integer
Private question As String, code As String
Private choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD As String
Private answer As String

 

Private Sub cmdA_Click()
'&H00C0FFFF& 'Normal
'&H0000FF00& 'Selected

cmdA.BackColor = &HFF00&
cmdB.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdC.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdD.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
btnClicked = "Answer: A"""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdB_Click()
cmdA.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdB.BackColor = &HFF00&
cmdC.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdD.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
btnClicked = "Answer: B"""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdC_Click()
cmdA.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdB.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdC.BackColor = &HFF00&
cmdD.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
btnClicked = "Answer: C"""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdD_Click()
cmdA.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdB.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdC.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdD.BackColor = &HFF00&
btnClicked = "Answer: D"""
End Sub

Sub resetButton()
cmdA.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdB.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdC.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
cmdD.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
End Sub

 

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
'Check if user click an option
If cmdA.BackColor = &HFF00& Or cmdB.BackColor = &HFF00& Or _
cmdC.BackColor = &HFF00& Or cmdD.BackColor = &HFF00& Then

'Move to the next question
questionNo = questionNo + 1
Label1.Caption = "Question " & questionNo & " of 10"

If cmdSubmit.Caption = "Submit" Then
Call get_quiz
Else

'Save the quiz result to record sheet
Dim lRow As Integer
lRow = rSH.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
rSH.Range("A" & lRow).Value = username
rSH.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Now
rSH.Range("C" & lRow).Value = score


frm_score.lblName = username
frm_score.lblScore = score
frm_score.Show
Unload Me
End If

Else
MsgBox "Please select an answer.", vbExclamation, mTitle
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
questionNo = 1
score = 0
Call init_SH
Call get_quiz
End Sub

Sub get_quiz()
Call resetButton
Dim lRow As Integer
lRow = questionNo + 1

question = qSH.Range("A" & lRow).Value

'code = qSH.Range("B" & lRow).Value
choiceA = qSH.Range("B" & lRow).Value
choiceB = qSH.Range("C" & lRow).Value
choiceC = qSH.Range("D" & lRow).Value
choiceD = qSH.Range("E" & lRow).Value
answer = qSH.Range("F" & lRow).Value

txtQuestion.Value = question
'txtSampleCode.Value = code          '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
cmdA.Caption = choiceA
cmdB.Caption = choiceB
cmdC.Caption = choiceC
cmdD.Caption = choiceD



If questionNo = 10 Then
'Last question
cmdSubmit.Caption = "End Exam"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Public userscore as integer` it will be available to all

Comment: I receive : Run Time Error 1004, Method Range of Object_Worksheet Failed.

    'Check if user click an option
    If cmdA.BackColor = &HFF00& Or cmdB.BackColor = &HFF00& Or _
    cmdC.BackColor = &HFF00& Or cmdD.BackColor = &HFF00& Then
    
    answer = qSH.Range("F" & lRow).Value     '<<----------------------------Line 
    highlighted

Comment: most likely there is an error in the range value `qSH.Range("F" & lRow).Value`

Comment: I'm still not having any luck getting this project finalized.      If anyone can give me guidance using the existing code posted above or even new code that works well I would be ever so grateful. Thanks.

Comment: The existing code is recording the correct # of answers like this :  https://share.internxt.com/d/sh/file/8b3d7700ab674b47e040/c3f59ee001ce4e9361f4ff829a51cd2ca58fa4e79e9319ee067e3f4a021c320d ............................ whereas it should be recording the data like this : https://share.internxt.com/d/sh/file/bcee8d5596f4ba78dff6/d19f5231b9a3a5d5d13e4bbb8d1c37a667be11d42f591ae5218994864f34da8c